# Index of an element in a filtered jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

So I have been searching for a couple of hours now and I haven't really found a solution yet.

It seems that the jQuery method .index() when calling on an element in a set, does not take the selector into regard.

To clarify, when I have a list of 5 li elements, where element 2, 3 and 4 have the class "foo". When I first filter these items with $('li.foo'), I get a set back with the size of 3 elements big. When I perform the .index() on the first item in the set like so $('li.foo').first().index(), instead of returning 0 (since it's the first item in the set and index starts counting from 0), it actually returns 1 (or in other words, the index for the second item).

Now with the example above it doesn't really seem necessary in my example to use index, but in my code I actually filter the filtered set( $('li.foo').filter('.active') ) to get a single item and then get the index of that item.

The problem it seems is that .index ignores the filters and selectors and I haven't had any luck in $.inArray();

If anyone could shed some light on how to get the index with a sure fire way, I would be super grateful!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do correctly, can you post a snippet so we can see an example of your code?  It doesn't have to be an actual copy-paste but some code demonstrating the problem you're facing would be helpful.

Comment: I will try to add a snippet as fast as possible :)

Comment: The main problem I was having is that .index() on a filtered list did not return the expected index number. Instead you have to 
filter twice by passing in a second selector. $filteredList.first().index() returns something different than $filteredList.index($filteredList.first())

I know it's confusing but it's something I bumped into

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index method have multiple variants to help in this regard

One you can call it on a set of elements and pass the [element whose index has to be found as an argument](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)

```
var $lis = $('li.foo');
var idx = $lis.index($lis.first());//will return 0
```

---

Another way is to pass the [selector as an argument](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) then index will return the index value based on the position of the current element relative to position of the element in the element set returned by the set of elements

```
var $el = $('li.foo').first();
var idx = $el.index('li.foo');
```

---

As for your problem

```
var $lis = $('li.foo'), $active = $('li.foo').filter('.active');
var index = $lis.index($active)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You would expect that $lis.first().index() would be enough to return the index while keeping the filter in mind (since you already filtered it and put it in $lis), but I guess it just requires more tricks to receive the desired output.